# Interview Question on Algorithms regarding Matrices

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

> You are provided with an N*M matrix containing Integer values. Your task is to select one integer from each row such that the sum of these integers is maximum. However, you are not allowed to select two integers from adjacent rows in the same column.

How can I do this problem in less than O(N^M) (or O(M^N))?

Comment: Hint: think about this as a graph problem where you want to find the shortest path. But the the weight of a path is here `max X - x` with `max X` the maximum of the matrix, and `x` the value of the cell. You can thus make it *O(n^2 m^2)*.

Comment: You can do this with dynamic programming in O(N*M) time.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two possible solutions: 1. using recursion, 2. using DP.

#### 1. Using Recursion

I think you already have this solution. I made a recursive function that goes through each row in matrix and calls recursion for each column. As you mentioned, the time complexity would be **O(M^N)** where N is the number of rows and M is the number of columns.

```
int getMaxSum(int[][] matrix) {
    return getMax(matrix, 0, -1);
}

int getMax(int[][] matrix, int row, int prevCol) {
    if (row >= matrix.length) return 0;

    int result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[row].length; i++) {
        if (i == prevCol) continue;

        int sum = getMax(matrix, row+1, i) + matrix[row][i];
        result = Math.max(result, sum);
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### 2. Using DP

Instead of recursively going through all rows and columns, I can use DP to keep track of maximum sum for each column up to a certain row. For example, `DP[r][c]` can have a maximum possible sum at column `c` up to row `r`. To implement this, I need to go through all rows and columns in the input matrix, and at each index, I also need to go through maximum possible sums at previous row (excluding the same column). This would result in time complexity of **O(N*M^2)** where N is the number of rows and M is the number of columns.

```
int getMaxSum(int[][] matrix) {
    if (matrix.length == 0) return 0;

    int[][] maxSumsDP = new int[matrix.length+1][matrix[0].length];
    for (int r = 1; r <= matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r-1].length; c++) {
            int maxPrev = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSumDP[r-1].length; i++) {
                if (i == c) continue;

                maxPrev = Math.max(maxPrev, maxSumsDP[r-1][i]);
            }
            maxSumsDP[r][c] = maxPrev + matrix[r-1][c];
        }
    }

    int result = maxSumsDP[maxSumsDP.length-1][0];
    for (int i = 1; i < maxSumsDP[maxSumsDP.length-1].length; i++) {
        result = Math.max(result, maxSumsDP[maxSumsDP.length-1][i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```